# How can I achieve this "rocky" wheel tread effect?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am modelling a tire and am looking for a way to reproduce this rocky tread effect onto my tire without having to do it manually.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This could be done with a displacement texture or geometry nodes, but by the time you figured it all out you could have modeled it. It's simple repeating geometry, so you'd only have to model one of the slices and array it around the tire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other two methods with modifiers other than geometry nodes are 1)**array** or 2) **displace**.

[image]

The classic method, array, requires drawing the curve shapes of the tread, and then applying a modifier stack. You must also have a circle or an empty to rotate the tread around the surface.  Your shapes should be parented to this object.  Your stack could look like this:

[image]

Displacement modifier will produce a good effect but it will produce alot more faces.  Unfortunately, you will have to find a way to reduce your mesh faces. This can be done with decimate or limited dissove.

You need a tileable texture to start with.  I found that marking a single seam on the inside, and using the option **follow active quads** worked in the end for this.

[image]

As user psyonic said, array modifier is probably the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

Replicating that exact pattern would (probably) be quite time consuming and I would recommend making it manually. However, making tire like patterns is fairly straight forward using some node combinations.

[image: Nodes and result]

The most important combo is Extrude Mesh > Scale Elements > Extrude Mesh, this lets you make raised sections. The Normal cross product with y-axis (or whatever axis the wheel rotates around) gives you a tangent of the wheel which lets you shift things along the wheel.

The base model was made using a Supertoroid with a subdivision surface applied. Supertoroids are from the built-in addon "Add Mesh: Extra Objects".